# get_it with Flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, provider, get-it

What the need for get_it in Bloc implementation as we are already using BLOC Provider for dependency injection ?

I'm currently using bloc provider for Dependency Injection and how get_it package was useful over Bloc Provider ? Needs clarification

Answer (score 0):

`get_it` will be useful when you use it to register Repository, DB, API Client instance, UseCases,..

Maybe your question is creating a bloc using `get_it` like `registerFactory<FooBloc>()`. If your question is like that: `get_it` will help create a block instance based on the dependencies you registered previously, it will help you not have to code a lot if that block is provided in many places. Finally, you still have to use `BlocProvider` to provide blocks down the widget tree. You must use `BlocProvider` because Bloc will live in the widget lifecycle and its context, so it will be easy to manage the initialization or closure of the Bloc via Widget.

If use `get_it`:

```dart
    BlocProvider(
      create: () => getIt<FooBloc>()
    )
```

If not use `get_it`

```dart
    BlocProvider(
      create: () => FooBloc(),
      child: FooWidget()
    )
```

If your `FooBloc` has dependences:

When using `get_it`, you register Bloc first:

```dart
    registerFactory<FooBloc>(
          () => FooBloc(
            depA: injector(),
            depB: injector(),
            depC: injector(),
          ),
```

and provide it via `BlocProvider` and other places you want to provide:

```dart
    BlocProvider(
      create: () => getIt<FooBloc>(),
      child: FooWidget()
    )
```

In case if you not use `get_it`:

```dart
    BlocProvider(
      create: () => FooBloc(
            depA: injector(),
            depB: injector(),
            depC: injector(),
          ),
      child: FooWidget()
    )
```

You will need to do the same if you want to provide to other place.

Hope my explanation will resolve your question. Happy coding <3

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
In both cases with get_it and without get_it , we are going to register in bloc Provider only once. And in which way get_it was better ?

Comment: if you use get_it, just go ahead to use get_it, if you don't want, you can use without get_it. Any way is fine